# Nome do aplicativo não aparece após baixar da APP Store

Tags: ios, apple, telerik

Desenvolvi um aplicativo no APP BUILDER e publiquei na APP STORE, porém no último update reparei que agora, quando baixa o aplicativo, ele aparece com o ícone e sem nome nos celulares (todas as versões do IOS)

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Não alterei nada de configuração

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nome do aplicativo fica dentro do arquivo Info.plist no atributo Bundle Name. Você pode apagar o valor padrão e escrever o nome do seu aplicativo nele. Caso este atributo não esteja criado, recomendo que crie.